# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel' but this dictionary requires a model item of type

Tags: presentation, mvc

While accessing the link on website got the below error.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred.

```
 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SLB.Entities.PrivateCommunity.PrivateCommunityFAQModel'.

Source Error: 

Line 81:         
Line 82:             
Line 83:                 @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("PrivateCommunityFAQs")
Line 84:             
Line 85:             

Source File: p:\Inetpub\sitehome\Views\Communities\Resources.cshtml    Line: 83 

Stack Trace: 

[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SLB.Entities.PrivateCommunity.PrivateCommunityFAQModel'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +214
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +155
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +137
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +137
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/Views/Communities/FAQs.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +148
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +75
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +184
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +259
   ASP._Page_Views_Communities_Resources_cshtml.Execute() in p:\WebApp\Website\Views\Communities\Resources.cshtml:83
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +137
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/Views/Communities/Resources.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +148
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +75
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +184
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +259
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared_Home_cshtml.Execute() in p:\WebApp\Website\Views\Shared\Home.cshtml:269
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +137
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/Views/Shared/Home.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +148
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +75
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +193
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +302
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +375
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +90
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This standard MVC error says that the strongly typed view */Views/Communities/FAQs.cshtml* does not match the model passed to it. Here is a full answer on your question https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/109

Comment: @Vyascheslav: I had tried to implement the solution as suggested above but it has started giving another error as  **Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index**.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred. 
Line 38:                              if (Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Model.ListEventName[0].Value).ParentID.ToString() ==Constants.PrivateCommunityDocumentsId

Comment: @PushpendraVats: You have this error, because your model has not been populated. The model type is correct, but an array here `.ListEventName` is empty. There are various ways how to populate the custom models in Sitecore MVC. If one uses a controller rendering, then the model is populated in the appropriate action method. If a view rendering is used, then you might inherit the model class from the `I/RenderingModel` and implement/override the `Initialize` method to initialize the model.

Comment: @PushpendraVats: Your original question has been answered. You might accept this answer.

Comment: @Vyascheslav: I am checking the answer and to implement it and yes, if this resolved the issue, will surely accept the answer. Thanks for all your valuable support and response.